# CakePHP how to set Content type header in appController?

Tags: php, json, cakephp, static-methods

I would like to have shared function for all extended controllers which print give json object as response.

I placed this shared function into the **"AppContoller.php"** as static function.

Problem is that i cannot access to this-> in AppController.

Question is:

**How can i solve it?**

Here is the code of the function:

```
public static function printJsonOutput($responseData)
{
    $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('json');
    $this->autoRender = false;
    echo json_encode($responseData);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: why static? you don't have access to `$this` in a static function

Comment: If i make it public i got this error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function respondAs() on a non-object in

Comment: Why do you want add your own hacks to output json when there is already [Json View](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

[Read the book about json and XML views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html).

What you want to do is explained there in great detail, with code examples and shown the right way to do it.

What you do is wrong and like @Nunser already pointed out you don't have access to $this in a static function. You might want to do some OOP tutorial for php first?